# Node.js installation stuck

Tags: node.js

I have downloaded Node.js .msi installer. It has successfully installed, but there are issues with required software installation. It should download everything on it's own, but it got stuck here:

`DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.`

Can i just quit and it will work, or i should do something to ensure that Node.js will work properly?

Comment: It should be working fine.

Comment: If “It has successfully installed” means the installer finished, what is “required software installation”?

Comment: @Ry- Chocolatey for example. It will open CMD after installation. Either way it closed on it's own, so i presume it's fine.

Answer (score 11):

It just happened to me. It got stuck for nearly 10 minutes with the exact same message as the last output.

Eventually it did finish though. There's little to nothing left afterwards but still, I'd advise that you let the script end gracefully rather than killing it.

Comment: Yeah.. happened to me.., it appears stuck for 20 minutes or so.. while I was googling about this the script eventually continue and completed the installation.